# Dynamic form, with or without multipart/form-data

Tags: java, html, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am designing a simple CRUD framework in java, where in my HTML page I have a dynamic form (2 with multipart for create and update with file upload and 1 without fileupload and multipart for delete). Server side, a request modulator checks for all the parameters using `request.getParameterMap();` and checks from this hidden type input `<input type="hidden" name="returntype" value="Create">` whether its a create, update or delete operation. Based on that it will call necessary handlers.

> Note: My form enctype and encoding is set to **multipart/form-data** 
>   Note: My paramMap.size() returns 0 here and returnType is getting null and so I am getting null pointer exception.

If I do not use enctype and encoding at all it runs fine, but then again my file upload gives me an exception that encoding type shoud be **multipart/form-data**. Can anyone help me in a way that I can have a dynamic form with which I can create a CRUD? or why am I not able to use `request.getParameterMap();` with **multipart/form-data** Thanks :)

Given below is the code of request modulator

```
public String identifyNow()throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
{
    UploadXmlAgent uploadAgent;
    paramMap=request.getParameterMap();
    if (paramMap == null)
        throw new ServletException(
          "getParameterMap returned null in: " + getClass().getName());

    iterator=paramMap.entrySet().iterator();
    System.out.println(paramMap.size());
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)iterator.next();
        if(me.getKey().equals("returntype"))
        {
            String[] arr=(String[])me.getValue();
            returnType=arr[0];
        }
    }

    //Identified based on returnType, instantiate appropriate Handler

    if(returnType.equals("Create"))
    {
        uploadAgent=new UploadXmlAgent(realPath,request,paramMap);
        uploadAgent.retrieveXml();
                    //SOME MORE OPERATIONS  
        return uploadAgent.uploadXml();
    }
    else if(returnType.equals("Update"))
    {
        System.out.println("Update");
        uploadAgent=new UploadXmlAgent(realPath,request,paramMap);
        uploadAgent.retrieveXml();
                    //SOME MORE OPERATIONS
        return uploadAgent.uploadXml();
    }
    else if(returnType.equals("Delete"))
    {
        //SOME OPERATIONS
    }
    return returnType;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment on the other answer:

> *can I use `request.getParameterMap();` in any way with multipart?*

If that is your sole requirement, then just create a `Filter` which does the parsing work and prepares the request parameter map with all those parsed multipart items so that you can continue using `getParameter()`, `getParameterMap()` and consorts the usual way in JSP/Servlet. You can find a complete example of such a filter [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html).

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should take a look at [Commons IO FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

To make a difference what kind of form is submitted, you can use a hidden input field

```
 <input type="hidden" name="formAction" value="uploadSomething">
```

Then you can use this in your Servlet to do the action depending on your form

```
String act = request.getParameter("formAction");
if(act.equals("uploadSomething")
{ 
// EDIT
if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
{

// Create a factory for disk-based file items
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
}
}
```

That's it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @Achim: I edited my question to show my hidden input type also, from which I am trying to find what type of operation it is.

Comment: did you checked that your request is a multipart/fileupload ?
`boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);`

Comment: @Achim: I revised and checked. Its true, multipart

Comment: take a look at my first reply, I added some line. You should take a look at the FileUpload Link I provided. It is all there

Comment: @Achim: Thanks :) I am aware of DiskFileItemFactory and ServletFileUpload> I am using these in my appropriate handler classes (create and update) to upload files and using `item.isFormField()` and `item.getFieldName()` I can get what i want, but I wanted to keep it separate. So the question is can I use  `request.getParameterMap();` in any way with multipart? I am also looking into oreilly multipart parser http://www.servlets.com/cos/index.html This might help too.

Comment: @Abhishek Simon As far as I know, the answer is **no**. 
I never used it in this combination so far...

Comment: @Achim: I'll keep a post once I made a way across this, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score -1):

Hi I managed to work it out.
I am using 2 requests and a session variable.

1st request to submit the form without multipart and store the request type in the session variable.

once the 1st request is sent, go for 2nd request of the same form, but this time use multipart and check your session variable value and execute appropriate handler.