# How do I know if form submission is successful?

Tags: java, html, servlets, jquery

I have a form, basically to upload a file. I am submitting the form twice, 1 without multipart and the 2nd 1 with multipart.

```
<input  type="button"  tabindex="5"  value="Create" id="btnS" class="btn" onClick="submitForm(this.form,'/test/upload'); return false;" />


//1st submission
form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
form.setAttribute("method","post");
form.submit();

//2nd submission
form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
form.setAttribute("method","post");
form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
form.submit();
```

but instead I want to 1st check if the 1st form submission is successful then go for 2nd submition

Edited after referring @Vern

```
var postString = getPostString();
var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange=handler(form,url_action);
client.open("POST",url_action,true);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postString.length);
client.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
client.send(postString);

function handler(form,url_action)
 {
     if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
//Here submitted is the text that I receive from the servlet If 1st submit is successful
         if (xmlhttp.responseText == "submitted"){
             secondSend(form,url_action);
            } else {
                alert("Not good!");
            }
         }
 }
 function getPostString()
 {

 }
 function secondSend(form,url_action)
 {
 form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
 form.setAttribute("method","post");
 form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
 form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
 form.submit();
 }
```

Here is my servlet part. where I am identifying if its multipart or not. If not store the **resultType** to a session variable then return `submitted`,

> Now I want to check for this "**submitted**" or similar and go for submitting the form 2nd time.

2nd Form submission: Here I will check if its multipart again, and check the session variable and go for CRUD. (This IdentifyNow is basically a kind of request modulator)

```
public String identifyNow()throws ServletException, java.io.IOException
{
    UploadXmlAgent uploadAgent;
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    System.out.println("\n\n*********************************\nisMultipart: "+isMultipart);

    if(isMultipart)
    {
        session=request.getSession(false);

        System.out.println("\nThis is multipart and isNew"+session.isNew());
        if(session!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("\ninside session");
            requestType=session.getAttribute("resultType").toString();
            //Identified based on requestType, instantiate appropriate Handler
            //session.invalidate();
            if(requestType.equals("Create"))
            {
                uploadAgent=new UploadXmlAgent(realPath,request,paramMap);
                uploadAgent.retrieveXml();  
                return uploadAgent.uploadXml();
            }
            else if(requestType.equals("Update"))
            {

            }
            else if(requestType.equals("Delete"))
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Session is null";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\nNot a multipart");
        paramMap=request.getParameterMap();
        if (paramMap == null)
            throw new ServletException(
              "getParameterMap returned null in: " + getClass().getName());

        iterator=paramMap.entrySet().iterator();
        System.out.println("\n"+paramMap.size());
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            if(me.getKey().equals("resultType"))
            {
                String[] arr=(String[])me.getValue();
                requestType=arr[0];
                System.out.println("Inside returntype: "+requestType);
            }
        }
        session=request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("returntype", requestType);
        System.out.println("Session.isNew="+session.isNew());
        return "submitted";
    }
    return "noCreate";
}
```

Here is Javascript function which is used to submit form twice, look for **micoxUpload() function**.

```
/* standard small functions */
   function $m(quem){
 return document.getElementById(quem)
}
function remove(quem){
 quem.parentNode.removeChild(quem);
}
function addEvent(obj, evType, fn){
 // elcio.com.br/crossbrowser
    if (obj.addEventListener)
    obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, true)
if (obj.attachEvent)
    obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn)
}
function removeEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.detachEvent ) {
    obj.detachEvent( 'on'+type, fn );
  } else {
    obj.removeEventListener( type, fn, false ); }
} 
/* THE UPLOAD FUNCTION */
function micoxUpload(form,url_action,id_element,html_show_loading,html_error_http){

    /******
* micoxUpload - Submit a form to hidden iframe. Can be used to upload
* Use but dont remove my name. Creative Commons.
* Versão: 1.0 - 03/03/2007 - Tested no FF2.0 IE6.0 e OP9.1
* Author: Micox - Náiron JCG - elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com - micoxjcg@yahoo.com.br
* Parametros:
* form - the form to submit or the ID
* url_action - url to submit the form. like action parameter of forms.
* id_element - element that will receive return of upload.
* html_show_loading - Text (or image) that will be show while loading
* html_error_http - Text (or image) that will be show if HTTP error.
*******/

 //testing if 'form' is a html object or a id string
 form = typeof(form)=="string"?$m(form):form;

 var erro="";
 if(form==null || typeof(form)=="undefined"){ erro += "The form of 1st parameter does       not exists.\n";}
 else if(form.nodeName.toLowerCase()!="form"){ erro += "The form of 1st parameter its not a form.\n";}
 if($m(id_element)==null){ erro += "The element of 3rd parameter does not exists.\n";}
 if(erro.length>0) {
  alert("Error in call micoxUpload:\n" + erro);
  return;
 }


 //creating the iframe
 var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.setAttribute("id","micox-temp");
 iframe.setAttribute("name","micox-temp");
 iframe.setAttribute("width","0");
 iframe.setAttribute("height","0");
 iframe.setAttribute("border","0");
 iframe.setAttribute("style","width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

 //add to document
 form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
 window.frames['micox-temp'].name="micox-temp"; //ie sucks

 //add event
   var carregou = function() { 
   removeEvent( $m('micox-temp'),"load", carregou);
   var cross = "javascript: ";
   cross += "window.parent.$m('" + id_element + "').innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML; void(0); ";

   $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_error_http;
   $m('micox-temp').src = cross;
   //del the iframe
   setTimeout(function(){ remove($m('micox-temp'))}, 250);
  }
 addEvent( $m('micox-temp'),"load", carregou)

 //properties of form
 /*form.setAttribute("target","micox-temp");
 form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
 form.setAttribute("method","post");*/
 //form.submit();


 var postString = getPostString();
 var client; 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 client=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {                    // IE6, IE5
 client=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 //client.onreadystatechange=handler(form,url_action);
 client.open("POST",url_action,true);
 client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 client.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postString.length);
 client.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
 client.onreadystatechange   =   function(){

 if (client.readyState==4 && client.status==200){
     alert(client.responseText); //This gives back my text from servlet
     secondSend(form,url_action);
 }
 };
 client.send($postStr);

 alert("1st request send");
 //secondSend(form,url_action);

 //while loading
 if(html_show_loading.length > 0){
  $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_show_loading;
 }
function getPostString()
 {
 $postStr=document.getElementsByTagName("confname");
 $postStr+=document.getElementsByTagName("returntype");
 return $postStr;
 }
     function secondSend(form,url_action)
 {

 form.setAttribute("target","micox-temp");
 form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
 form.setAttribute("method","post");
 form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
 form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
 form.submit();
 if(html_show_loading.length > 0){
  $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_show_loading;
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. Why would you submit a form twice with different encodings? Use the right encoding from the beginning on.

Comment: @BalusC: I making 2 requests 1st to send all the form data as in multipart the whole content is changed and I wanted to use any of the `request.getParameter...` functions. so 2nd request time, the form is submitted by multipart so this way I can fetch the form data from session and continue. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I've already answered your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829052/dynamic-form-with-or-without-multipart-form-data

Comment: @BalusC: Ya I referred your answer for `request.getParameterMap();` Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

submit() does not have a return value and as such you are not able to check the outcome of the submission just based on your code above.

However, the common way to do it is actually to use Ajax and use a function to set a flag. That way, you can check if the form is successfully submitted. Not to mention, with the server reply, you can further validate if the form has been transmitted correctly to the server :)

Hope it helped. Cheers!

---

The following code should give you an idea of how to do it:

```
function first_send(){
    // Local Variable
    var xmlhttp;            

        // Create Object
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {                    // IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

        // Set Function
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        // (1) Check reply from server if request has been successfully 
        //     received
        // (2) Set flag / Fire-off next function to send
        // Example
        if (xmlhttp.responseText == "ReceiveSuccess"){
          secondSend();
        } else {
          // Error handling here
      } 
      } 
    }

        // Gets the first set of Data you want to send
    var postString = getPostString();  

          // Send
    xmlhttp.open("POST","form1.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postString.length);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(postString);
}
```

And you'll need:

```
function getPostString(){
          // Collect data from your form here
}

function secondSend(){
      // You can create this function and post like above
      // or just do a direct send like your code did
}
```

Hope it helps (:

---

This code ought to do the trick, but be sure to fill up with the HTML form that you're using! Also, put the first form in a submission if you require:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var postString = getPostString();
  var client     = new XMLHttpRequest();  // You shouldn't create it this way.

            // Open Connection and set the necessary
        client.open("POST",url_action,true);
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        client.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postString.length);
        client.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            // Create function
        client.onreadystatechange   =   function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                if (xmlhttp.responseText == "Success") {
                    secondSend();
                } else {
                    alert('In Error');
                }
            }
        };

        client.send(postString);

  function getPostString()
  {
    // Get your postString data from your form here

        // Return your Data to post
        return $postStr;
  }

  function secondSend()
  {
        // Make sure you fill up your form before you post

    form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
    form.setAttribute("method","post");
    form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
    form.submit();
  }    
</script>
```

Comment: @Vem: Thanks it was a good info for me. Also can you guide me how to use ajax to do that? thanks

Comment: I couldn't squeeze all that code into the comment, so check out the code after the horizontal break line (: Cheers!

Comment: @Vern:I guess I need to do a lot of studying.. Thanks though, this might help :)

Comment: No worries, just post back a question if you have any problems. I'm pretty sure the community is willing to help. Cheers!

Comment: @Vern: <b>getPostString()</b> where do I store the form data here? Please check my edited question, that I followed from your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Vern: I get nothing when I refer to `xmlhttp.responseText` :( please help

Comment: Hey there see my above answer, but do make sure you fill up the rest (:

Comment: @Vern: Thanks, sorry I am such a trouble, I am new to developing. With `return $postStr;` do you mean I should get data from form using HTML DOM and append it in poststr? As when I made changes, filled up my form, after submission it does not show anything.

Comment: No worries, yes you are right, you need to fill up $postStr with data collected from your form. When you do that, maybe you could echo it so that you can see if your collection of data from the form is correct.

Comment: @Vern: Thanks for your polite reply. I am able to receive all form values in my servlet using `request.getParameterMap();` so I won't be needing that right? I want a confirmation from my servlet (after 1st submission) that yes now you can go for your 2nd form submission. May be we landed some place else :)

Comment: @Vern: I included my servlet too. so you can get a even better idea of what I doing at server side. Sorry I am taking too much of your time. Thanks again a lot, for helping me get so far with learning.

Comment: Great to hear that you can get your first form submission correct at the server end. Now, all you have to do is for your server to echo a reply to the client. See my edited code above with the xmlhttp.responseText == "Success". This means that you must echo back the text "Success" from your server to the client. Hope you can get things to work now :)

Comment: @Vern: I placed a `alert(xmlhttp.responseText);` inside `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){` but it does not seem to work :( but if I provide a, `out.println("submitted");` in my server side, after 1st form submit, it displays that in my page

Comment: @Vern: The problem of my last comment is that, I am not able to submit my form using `XMLHttpRequest` ... `client.send();` but instead this  `form.submit();` makes my 1st form submit and also print `submitted` in my browser

Comment: Hi, when you say "does not work", does it mean that xmlhttp.responseText is returning you an empty string? You should not be using from.submit() for the first form if you want to use the XMLHttp object to send. Also, what browser are you using? The 2nd code that I posted which is modified from your original code. The XMLHttp object should not be created that way.

Comment: @Vern: Thanks for pointing out about usage of XMLHttp object I corrected that. The alert itself is not coming. I was using `form.submit` before, but after using `client.send();` my form is not getting submitted. For more detail I am editing my question to include my javascript function that is called when button is clicked

Comment: Hi, you are not sending anything because your 'client.send();' has an empty parentheses. It should be changed to 'client.send(postString);'. That should do the trick :)

Comment: @Vern: Oh! Thanks a lot Vern you pointed out my mistake. If it were for me I would have given whole lot of rep points. I just need to figure out how to parse the submitted `client.send($postStr);` and I'm done. I'll let you know when I am fully done. Thanks again. I updated my code. :) 1 more help, in server side how will I get data from `$postStr`

Comment: No worries :) As for your server side, you'll just need to parse the text that you get at the server side. Once you can output at the server side what you get from your client, it's pretty straight forward :)

Comment: @Vern: Today I went for a ajax approach it worked and is much simpler for me, I am sharing my stuff with you. I will also complete our discussion in this weekend :) Here is the link and person's name that helped me in that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895354/accessing-form-elements-using-jquery-and-dom by Felix Kling

Comment: Great to hear that you've got your problem solved :) Thanks for sharing :) That's the other way to do it which at times is more convenient for a quick fire up :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the ajax way of doing it apart from the regular XMLHttpRequest by @Vern

```
/*CALLING 1st SUBMIT*/
$(function() {
$("#submitButton").click(callme);

function callme() {      
    var form=document.forms["yourFormID"];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/upload",
        data: {resulttype: $('#resulttype').val()},
        async:false,
        complete: function(msg){

            micoxUpload(form,'/upload','postUploadInformation','Loading...','Crap! something went wrong'); return false;
        }
     });
}

});

/* THE UPLOAD FUNCTION */
function micoxUpload(form,url_action,id_element,html_show_loading,html_error_http){

/******
* micoxUpload - Submit a form to hidden iframe. Can be used to upload
* Use but dont remove my name. Creative Commons.
* Versão: 1.0 - 03/03/2007 - Tested no FF2.0 IE6.0 e OP9.1
* Author: Micox - Náiron JCG - elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com - micoxjcg@yahoo.com.br
* Parametros:
* form - the form to submit or the ID
* url_action - url to submit the form. like action parameter of forms.
* id_element - element that will receive return of upload.
* html_show_loading - Text (or image) that will be show while loading
* html_error_http - Text (or image) that will be show if HTTP error.
*******/

 //testing if 'form' is a html object or a id string
 form = typeof(form)=="string"?$m(form):form;

 var erro="";
 if(form==null || typeof(form)=="undefined"){ erro += "The form of 1st parameter does   not exists.\n";}
 else if(form.nodeName.toLowerCase()!="form"){ erro += "The form of 1st parameter its not a form.\n";}
 if($m(id_element)==null){ erro += "The element of 3rd parameter does not exists.\n";}
 if(erro.length>0) {
  alert("Error in call micoxUpload:\n" + erro);
  return;
 }


 //creating the iframe
 var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.setAttribute("id","micox-temp");
 iframe.setAttribute("name","micox-temp");
 iframe.setAttribute("width","0");
 iframe.setAttribute("height","0");
 iframe.setAttribute("border","0");
 iframe.setAttribute("style","width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

 //add to document
 form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
 window.frames['micox-temp'].name="micox-temp"; //ie sucks

 //add event
 var carregou = function() { 
   removeEvent( $m('micox-temp'),"load", carregou);
   var cross = "javascript: ";
   cross += "window.parent.$m('" + id_element + "').innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;  void(0); ";

   $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_error_http;
$m('micox-temp').src = cross;
//del the iframe
setTimeout(function(){ remove($m('micox-temp'))}, 250);
}
 addEvent( $m('micox-temp'),"load", carregou)

 secondSend(form,url_action);

 //while loading
 if(html_show_loading.length > 0){
  $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_show_loading;
 }

 function secondSend(form,url_action)
 {

 form.setAttribute("target","micox-temp");
 form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
 form.setAttribute("method","post");
 form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
 form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
 form.submit();

 if(html_show_loading.length > 0){
  $m(id_element).innerHTML = html_show_loading;
 }
 }
}
```